# how to add query string to mongo DB query in spring boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, microservices

I have a requirement as below.

getting where clause as string from UI, any option to add string in where clause in **spring boot** to query **mongo DB**

Eg:*(eventType BEGINSWITH 'asdf' AND age > fasdf) AND(age <= 123 OR book NOT ENDSWITH '2344444')*

in sql we can add in where clause,but not sure how we can do this in springboot for mongodb

Note: String is dynamic and do not have specific pattern. Parenthesis can be nested. front end angular and service in spring boot

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

using spring data use @Query and pass your find query in value param
like

@Query( "{$and : [{'customUser.id':  ?0},{'deleted' : false}],$or:[{'current_location' : true}, {'resident_of' : true}]}")

List findAllByCustomUserA(String userId);

solution for your issue

@Query(value = "{$and : [{'eventType': {$regex:'asdf/',$options:'i'}}, {'age': {$lte : 123}}, {$or[{'book' : {$regex:'/2344444',$options:'i'}}]} ]}")

for more details visit how to make mongo query

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: Sumit, thanks for your reply, But here string is dynamic and we dont know what are the columns coming in that string.

Comment: @Query( "{$and : [{'customUser.id': ?0},{'deleted' : false}],$or:[{'current_location' : true}, {'resident_of' : true}]}")

List findAllByCustomUserA(String userId);

?0 use for dynamic string in this example ?0 use string of userId, use same in your issue 0,1,2 is index of param in methos

Comment: this will work, if columns are fixed , if the no. of columns are not fixed , i dont think we can go this approach

Comment: use aggrigation machanism if columns are vary

Comment: It would great, if you could provide sample or reference

Comment: Go through this

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-projections-aggregations

this helps you in staring with mongodb aggregation